# Google drive, Firebase different client ids for same iOS app

Tags: firebase, google-drive-api, firebase-authentication, google-signin, gtm-oauth2

First, I integrated Google Drive in my iOS native app and used GTMOAuth2 for authorization login, with a client id.

Then, I am now trying to integrate firebase authentication, and I got a new client id in GoogleService-Info.plist.

When I used firebase authorization and then got the data in google drive, I got an Invalid Credentials error.

How can I use firebase authorization to get the data in google drive? Why does the same APP have two client ids, can I modify the client id in GoogleService-Info.plist?

Comment: Accessing files in Drive API require [certain scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) - read and write, so OAuth is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have added the Google Drive API scope, but when I use the new client id in GoogleService-Info.plist, I still get error = "invalid_client".

Answer (score 0):

I have passed through the same. After Enable GglDrive api ,In Credential, Don't create new credential you'll find in below list(auto created by google services),You'll find one id with same ClientId & ReturnUrl like in Google.plist. Use to download that file and use. You'll not face this "invalid_client" error further. Check image below I have shown with arrow:

[image]